# mapedit change color and opacity

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, r-sf, r-leaflet

I have a simple app that allows a user to draw a feature.
How can I also allow the user to select the fill colour and opacity by providing a hex code.

Reproducible example:

```
library(mapedit)
library(mapview)
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    editModUI("editor"),
    colourInput('colour', "Select Colour", allowTransparent = TRUE)
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  edits <- callModule(editMod, "editor", mapview()@map)

  ### need to somehow adjust the color and/or opacity of the drawn features based on input$colour

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```